# How to replace specific letters in string without touching the words and letters inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all spaces in a string expect if the spaces are inside quotes. I want the text inside the quotes to not to be touched at all.
I know this `regexr` `!((".+")|('.+'))` but I don't know how to implement it.

```
const value = " text text ' text in quotes no touch' "
value.replaceAll(' ', '+')
// wanted results "+text+text+' text in quotes no touch'+"
```

**my goal**
 `value.replaceAll(if !((".+")|('.+')) then change ' ' to '+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression `string OR space` and a callback function that returns `+` only if the match is a space:

```js
const value = " text text ' text in quotes no touch' "
const repl = value.replace(/'.+?'| /g, m => m === ' ' ? '+' : m)
console.log(repl)
```

To handle escaped quotes, the "string" part can be refined to `'(\\.|[^'])+'`

```js
const value = " text text ' text in \\' quotes no touch' "
const repl = value.replace(/'(\\.|[^'])+'| /g, m => m === ' ' ? '+' : m)
console.log(repl)
```

Comment: What would happen if a string within quotes could contain an escaped quote? eg, `'Would\'t you'`?

Comment: @georg great thank you, also do you know to to retun only digits when I have a digit with spaces after it?`"1  2  +1 ".replace(/(\d)( +)/g, (m, r,) => $1);` `$1` I mean I want to return only the first group of the regexr

Comment: @AliHusham: `"1  2  +1 ".replace(/\D/g, '')` gives you `121`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to regular expressions (which perhaps supply a better solution), you could traverse the string and infer, that every odd encounter of a quote marks the beginning of a quoted sentence:

```
value.split("'").map((line, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 0)
        // Even encounters of a quote --> We are outside a quote, so we replace
        return line.replaceAll(' ','+')
    else
        // Odd encounters --> We are inside a quote, so do nothing
        return line 
}).join('\'')
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: @ucMedia I was a little reluctant, since there are better answers, but I did it now anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could first split the string and then apply the replacement only to the substrings that don't start with a quote:

```
const value = " text text ' text in quotes no touch' "

const splits = value.split(/('.+')/g)   // [" text text ", "' text in quotes no touch'", " "]

const replaced = splits.map(substr => 

  substr.startsWith("'") ? substr : substr.replaceAll(" ", "+")

  ).join("")

console.log(replaced)
```